# Java program runs smoothly in Netbeans but slowly in Eclipse and as an executable jar

Tags: java, performance

A java program that does frequent swing/awt painting animation (but nothing more advanced than g.fillOval(...)) runs at a consistent 60fps in Netbeans, and at about 6fps when ran in Eclipse or executed as a jar file from a unix terminal. The program was developed in Netbeans and is run-of-the-mill desktop application (not webstart or japplet or ...). This is occurring in Ubuntu 10 with java 1.6. How is this possible?

> `$` <kbd>java -version</kbd>
>   java version "1.6.0_22"
>
> Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_22-b04)
>
> Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 17.1-b03, mixed mode, sharing)

---

Set the default jvm to the sun version, and outputed the jvm used by netbeans and the unix terminal, which was the same for both:

`java.runtime.name=Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment, sun.boot.library.path=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.22/jre/lib/i386, java.vm.version=17.1-b03, java.vm.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.`

However, this didn't make any difference as there is still a significant frame rate discrepancy. Is there some other factor that could be at play here?

Comment: In ubuntu are you running the Sun's JVM?

Comment: What does running "in NetBeans" actually mean? It's still a separate JVM process launched by NetBeans, is that correct? If so, is it possible to find out what command line is used by NB to launch it?

Comment: first of all post output of java --version.

Comment: OpenJDK != Sun's JDK :). Install Sun JDK and try again

Comment: Also, I believe you can examine system properties during runtime (System.getProperties()) and verify what JVM are you running in each case.

Comment: As Rogach stated in his answer: jvm parameters. Try playing with the memory settings, maybe you've got a GC running too often? Just a theory...

Comment: There is something really strange happening. I'd love to know what. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of possible reasons may be that NetBeans can use one JVM, and Eclipse and terminal "java" command can use another. Look into what platform NetBeans uses for your project, and compare it with Eclipse. 
 
Also there can be something with arguments you passed to JVM. Check that too.

Answer (score 1):

In Ubuntu there's a very handy utility. Try this:

```
sudo update-java-alternatives -s java-6-sun
```

in shell. It may output some errors...

```
update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for mozilla-javaplugin.so. 
update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for xulrunner-1.9-javaplugin.so. 
update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for mozilla-javaplugin.so. 
update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for xulrunner-1.9-javaplugin.so.
```

That's only a problem with java plugin for Firefox. You may ignore this. If you have any other problem, than check which java you've got installed by issuing:

```
sudo update-java-alternatives -l
```

Or, you may use the interactive version:

```
sudo update-java-alternatives --config
```

(... this one I haven't tested).

If for any reason You don't have Sun's JDK listed post a comment.

---

**EDIT**

Are you using hardware acceleration? Try adding this JVM property:

```
-Dsun.java2d.opengl=True
```

To see details you might also use:

```
-Dsun.java2d.trace=log
```

Consult [OpenGL acc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/2d/flags.html#opengl)  for more details.

Comment: The program doesn't use java2d and the graphics aren't sophisticated enough to require hardware acceleration. Something else is awry.

Comment: Doesn't use java2D? That's strange... What's your graphics stack? You know that java2D is used by Swing internally? EDIT: Just read your answer. Apparently you're using it without knowing it. You have `g.fillOval` where g is of type `java.awt.Graphics2D`?

Comment: Here's the code in case you are interested: https://sourceforge.net/projects/somelameapp/

Comment: Looking at it now. Oh my it's really nice! So far it runs smoothly on Windows 7 from NetBeans and command line (ant run). I'll install Ubuntu and see what's with it.

Comment: It may be it, or may not. There is a big catch with all Java2D and Swing code: all GUI code must run on EDT. If I'm reading correctly, than your component is updated in another thread ('Thread[Thread-2,6,main]' in my case'). The fix is simple. Just wrap any GUI related code (I see only call to `graphicPanel.repaint();` at line 842 of ApplicationLogic, but may be more) with SwingUtilities.invoke...() (just like you construct GUI in main method). Than again - it might be completely unrelated to slowdowns you're getting.

Comment: Sorry for chaotic commment. You might want to see http://mindprod.com/jgloss/swingthreads.html for a clearer and more thorough explanation.

Comment: Just for beauty: Have you tried adding `        g2.addRenderingHints(Collections.singletonMap(
                RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON));` before any rendering?